# PHP uploads only jpg format

Tags: php

Following the lead of MrCode i was able to detect why my upload was not going through for other picture format. Below is the createThumbs function, so how do i make it to work for other extensions.

```
<?php
function createThumbs( $pathToImages, $pathToThumbs, $thumbWidth ) 
{
 // open the directory
$dir = opendir( $pathToImages );

// loop through it, looking for any/all JPG files:
while (false !== ($fname = readdir( $dir ))) {
// parse path for the extension
$info = pathinfo($pathToImages . $fname);
// continue only if this is a JPEG image
if ( strtolower($info['extension']) == 'jpg' ) 
{
  // load image and get image size
  $img = imagecreatefromjpeg( "{$pathToImages}{$fname}" );
  $width = imagesx( $img );
  $height = imagesy( $img );

  // calculate thumbnail size
  $new_width = $thumbWidth;
  $new_height = floor( $height * ( $thumbWidth / $width ) );

  // create a new tempopary image
  $tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor( $new_width, $new_height );

  // copy and resize old image into new image 
  imagecopyresized( $tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width,   $height );

  // save thumbnail into a file
  imagejpeg( $tmp_img, "{$pathToThumbs}{$fname}" );
}
}
// close the directory
closedir( $dir );
}

?>
```

Comment: What error do you get and what script do you use (self made or a library).

Comment: Try to upload a sing `png` or `gif`.

Comment: The code posted is insensitive of the file type, I'm guessing your problem is in `createThumbs()`, probably because you're using the `imagejpg*()` functions only. You'll have to show the code for that function.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your loop

```
foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
```

should be written like

```
foreach($_FILES['files'] as $key => $file){
```

as the first will run only for first time and in the first `file` there may be a `jpeg` image
so it runs for the first time.

Comment: This is not the case. `$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key]` is the correct structure for multiple file uploads. See http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php